# How to take average value based on the range of another Variable in R?

Tags: r, time, range

I have time as my variable v1 and occupancy rate as my v2.

```
   Interval    Percentage
    18:00:00   100%
    18:00:00    99%
    18:00:00    98%
    18:00:00   100%
    18:30:00    89%
    18:30:00    88%
    18:30:00    90%
    19:00:00    93%
    19:00:00    92%
    19:00:00    93%
```

Say I want to take the average of occupancy for interval 18:00:00, how am I supposed to do with R? I tried the following:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(B, .(B$Interval), summarize, mean_y=mean(B$Percentage)) 

   B$Interval     mean_y 
1    18:30:00  0.6795594 
2    18:35:00  0.6795594 
3    18:40:00  0.6795594
4    18:45:00  0.6795594
5    18:50:00  0.6795594
6    18:55:00  0.6795594
7    19:00:00  0.6795594
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you search here for similar problem?

Comment: I have tried using plyr func. but the avg value turned out to be repetitive.
> library(plyr)
> ddply(B, .(B$Interval), summarize, mean_y=mean(B$Percentage))
   B$Interval    mean_y
1    18:30:00 0.6795594
2    18:35:00 0.6795594
3    18:40:00 0.6795594
4    18:45:00 0.6795594
5    18:50:00 0.6795594
6    18:55:00 0.6795594
7    19:00:00 0.6795594

Comment: It appears that the `B` you used in your `plyr` code is not the example data you included in your question. Please update your question by providing `B`, possibly using the `dput` function. You can read more about producing reproducible examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You don't need `B$` inside `ddply`

Comment: As akrun says, skip all the `B$` inside ddply and it will work. `mean(B$Percentage)` just calculates the overall mean of the Percentage column in all of B. `mean(Percentage)`, when used with `summarize` inside `ddply`, calculates the mean percentage for each subset of `B` with the given interval.

Comment: @akrun and mathemactical.coffee answers work! :)